# Может ли MySQL вызвать внешнюю программу по триггеру?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, триггер

Имеются ли какие нибудь способы по триггеру в MySQL вызвать например хранимую процедуру (выполнить в ней определенные действия с данными в таблицах) а затем вызвать внешнюю программу (скрипт, например PHP)?

Может какие то модули для MySQL могут такое?

Comment: да, делал такое. нужно установить доп. плагин для mysql: https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys и будет доступен новый метод `sys_exec`. почитайте как установить `LIB_MYSQLUDF_SYS`

Comment: @programmer403 Огромное спасибо! Почему бы не оформить как ответ?